# An expressjs server running on a separate port than the sveltekit app and setting cookie in the browser

Tags: cookies, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm a big fan of svelte. I'm testing sveltekit and ran into setting cookie in page.js
Here is my setup and code :

My server which is expressjs running on port 3000.

Now, I'm trying to use sveltekit frontapp with it. The sveltekit is running on port 5173 with node-adapter.

My express app handle, set the cookie the traditional expressjs way :

```
let cookieinfo = 'acookietestwhatevervalue'
res.cookie("onetwo", cookieinfo ).json({"data" : "somedata"})
```

In sveltekit, I have a index.svelte and page.js
in page.js I run fetch to my expressjs server handle with this code :

```
   let url = "api/getacookie"
 /** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {

     let response = await fetch(url) 
     console.log("see if response has set-cookie header :", response.headers)
 
     let aboutcookie = await response.json()


return {
    aboutcookie
}
}
```

When I inspect dev tools, there is no cookie with the name "onetwo" but response has the set cookie header :

```
HeadersList {
  cookies: [ 'onetwo=acookietestwhatevervalue; Path=/; SameSite=None' ],
  [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(22) {
    'content-security-policy' => {
      name: 'Content-Security-Policy',
```

I see the cookie in the response but when I check the dev tools cookies, the cookie is not there.

What am I missing here?